# Center Sliding Image on Different browsers

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

On the Sliding image on webpage[page banner], All I need to put it in the center rather than floating it on the left or right..

For HTML code

```
<ul class"rslides" id="slides">
  <li><img src"image/test.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src"image/test2.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

On CSS

```
.rslides
position:relative
overlow:hidden
padding:0
margin:0

.rslides li{
position:absolute
display:none
width :100%
left:0
right:0
```

how can i position my sliding image to be centered in the center of the home page..i opened in chrome and firefox both displayed to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;** to your parent B container  with some fixed width less than screen width. It will surely work

Comment: Great ,my pleasure you should vote the answer if it helps you